# Sort by category doesn't work in React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, object, methods

I assume my problem is in drilling down to get correct method from `sortTypes`?

My helper functions (Up, Down, Sort required to pull corresponding fontawesome icons):

```
const sortTypes = {
  Up: {
    fn: {
      age: (a, b) => (a.age - b.age ? 1 : -1),
      cores: (a, b) => (a.cpuUsage - b.cpuUsage ? 1 : -1),
      memory: (a, b) => (a.memoryUsage - b.memoryUsage ? 1 : -1)
    }
  },
  Down: {
    fn: {
      age: (a, b) => (b.age - a.age ? 1 : -1),
      cores: (a, b) => (b.cpuUsage - a.cpuUsage ? 1 : -1),
      memory: (a, b) => (b.memoryUsage - a.memoryUsage ? 1 : -1)
    }
  },
  Sort: {
    fn: {
      age: (a, b) => (b.age - a.age ? 1 : -1),
      cores: (a, b) => (b.cpuUsage - a.cpuUsage ? 1 : -1),
      memory: (a, b) => (b.memoryUsage - a.memoryUsage ? 1 : -1)
    }
  }
};

export default sortTypes;
```

And component that uses it:

```
class BottomPanel extends Component {
  state = {
    currentSort: 'Sort',
    category: ''
  };

  onSortChange = e => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.id);

    const { currentSort } = this.state;

    let nextSort, category;

    if (currentSort === 'Down') nextSort = 'Up';
    else if (currentSort === 'Up') nextSort = 'Sort';
    else if (currentSort === 'Sort') nextSort = 'Down';

    if (e.currentTarget.id === 'btn-age') category = 'age';
    else if (e.currentTarget.id === 'btn-cores') category = 'cores';
    else if (e.currentTarget.id === 'btn-memory') category = 'memory';

    this.setState({
      currentSort: nextSort,
      category: category
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.category);
    const { runningTasks } = this.props;
    const { currentSort, category } = this.state;

    return (
      runningTasks.length >= 0 && (
        <div className="bottom-panel">
          <div className="table-header row">
            <div className="column name">
              <span>Name</span>
            </div>
            <div className="column task-status">
              <span>Status</span>
            </div>
            <div className="column label">
              <span>Label</span>
            </div>
            <div className="column age">
              <span>
                Age
                <button id="btn-age" onClick={this.onSortChange}>
                  &nbsp;
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSort} />
                </button>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div className="column cluster-ip">
              <span>Cluster IP</span>
            </div>
            <div className="column cpu-usage">
              <span>CPU (cores)</span>
              <button id="btn-cores" onClick={this.onSortChange}>
                &nbsp;
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSort} />
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="column memory-usage">
              <span>Memory (bytes) </span>
              <button id="btn-memory" onClick={this.onSortChange}>
                &nbsp;
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSort} />
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="table-body">
            {[...runningTasks]
              .sort(sortTypes[currentSort].fn.category)
              .map((task, index) => (
                <div className="table-item row" key={index}>
                  <div className="column age">
                    <span>{task.age} minutes</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="column cpu-usage">
                    <span className="cpu-usage-chart">
                      <BottomBarChart data={task.cpuUsage} />
                    </span>
                    &nbsp;
                    <p style={{ fontSize: '8px' }}>{task.cpuUsage[0].high}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="column memory-usage">
                    <span className="memory-usage-chart">
                      <BottomBarChart data={task.memoryUsage} />
                    </span>
                    <p style={{ fontSize: '8px' }}>
                      &nbsp;
                      {task.memoryUsage[0].high} MiB
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    );
  }
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-cerf-52rvd)

Comment: .sort(sortTypes[currentSort].fn.category.) you have a syntax error..please fix it so that this code could be checked live

Comment: Thank you. It has been edited.

Comment: So what is the actual poblem? What do you mean drilling down the function? does the sorting logic work?

Comment: I thought a could use local state to construct a correct path to corresponding method through the sortTypes as sortTypes.currentSort.fn.category, but  it doesn't work. E.g. when button age clicked it has to sort items by age in descending order and if i click the same button it sort it in descending order. Just need someone to guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
.sort(sortTypes[currentSort].fn.category)
```

to this:

```
.sort(sortTypes[currentSort].fn[category])
```

I didn't try it cause your code requires some additional external modules, but this is clearly a mistake.

Edit: Being that you use sort() in your JSX, it was impossible to make it work with strings like "task-one"(sort() would sort it alphabetically), so i had to change to "task-1". Remember that you don't really sort by name, but **group by name.** Maybe it's possible to do it with sort(), but i don't know how.

I suggest not to use such logic within the render method, but rather to supply the already sorted/grouped data "from above".

Sort types:

```
const sortTypes = {
  Up: {
    fn: {
      age: (a, b) => (a.age > b.age ? -1 : a.age > b.age ? 1 : 0),
      status: ((a, b) => (a.status > b.status) ? 1 : -1),
      name: (a, b) =>{     

        return (a.name < b.name) ? 1 : -1;
      }
    }
  },
  Down: {
    fn: {
      age: (a, b) => (a.age < b.age ? -1 : a.age > b.age ? 1 : 0),
      status: ((a, b) => (a.status < b.status) ? 1 : -1),
      name: (a, b) =>{       

        return (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : -1

      }
    }
  },

};

export default sortTypes;
```

Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import sortTypes from "./sortTypes";
import data from "./data";

class BottomPanel extends Component {

  state = {
    currentSort: "Up",
    category: "",

  }; 
  onSortChange = category => {
    debugger;
    const { currentSort } = this.state;
    let direction;
    if(category !== this.state.category){
      direction ='Up'
    }else{
       direction = currentSort === 'Down' ? 'Up': 'Down';    
    }  

    this.setState({
      currentSort: direction,
      category: category
    });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.category, this.state.currentSort);
    const { currentSort, category } = this.state;

    return (
      data.length >= 0 && (
        <div className="bottom-panel">
          <div className="table-header row">
            <div className="column name">
              <span>Name</span>
              <button id="btn-cores" onClick={()=>{this.onSortChange('name')}}>
                Sort by name
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="column task-status">
              <span>Status</span>
              <button id="btn-cores" onClick={()=>{this.onSortChange('status')}}>
                Sort by status
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="column label">
              <span>Label</span>
            </div>
            <div className="column age">
              <span>
                Age
                <button id="btn-age" onClick={()=>{this.onSortChange('age')}}>
                  Sort by age
                </button>
              </span>
            </div>
            <div className="column cluster-ip">
              <span>Cluster IP</span>
            </div>
            <div className="column cpu-usage">
              <span>CPU (cores)</span>
              {/* <button id="btn-cores" onClick={()=>{this.onSortChange('cores')}}>
                Sort by CPU
              </button> */}
            </div>
            <div className="column memory-usage">
              <span>Memory (bytes) </span>
              {/* <button id="btn-memory" onClick={()=>{this.onSortChange('memory')}}>
                Sort by memory
              </button> */}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="table-body">
            {[...data]
              .sort(sortTypes[currentSort].fn[category])
              .map((task, index) => (
                <div className="table-item row" key={index}>
                  <div className="column name">
                    <span>{task.name}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="column task-status">
                    <span>{task.status}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="column label">
                    <span>{task.label}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="column age">
                    <span>{task.age} minutes</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="column cluster-ip">
                    <span>{task.clusterIP}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="column cpu-usage">
                    <span className="cpu-usage-chart">
                      {task.cpuUsage[0].high}
                    </span>
                    &nbsp;
                  </div>
                  <div className="column memory-usage">
                    <span className="memory-usage-chart">
                      {task.memoryUsage[0].high}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    );
  }
}

export default BottomPanel;
```

Data:

```
const data = [
  {
    status: "Not available",
    label: "task-label",
    age: 23,
    name: "task-1",
    clusterIP: "10.148.0.3",
    cpuUsage: [
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 1:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 0.12,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 2:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 0.105,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 3:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 0.1,
        low: 20
      }
    ],
    memoryUsage: [
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 1:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 100,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 2:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 10,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 3:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 50,
        low: 20
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    status: "Running",
    label: "task-label",
    age: 27,
    name: "task-2",
    clusterIP: "10.148.0.3",
    cpuUsage: [
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 1:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 0.06,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 2:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 0.105,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 3:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 0.1,
        low: 20
      }
    ],
    memoryUsage: [
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 1:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 570,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 2:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 550,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 3:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 540,
        low: 20
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    status: "Running",
    label: "task-label",
    age: 21,
    name: "task-3",
    clusterIP: "10.148.0.3",
    cpuUsage: [
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 1:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 0.04,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 2:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 0.09,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 3:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 0.13,
        low: 20
      }
    ],
    memoryUsage: [
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 1:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 570,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 2:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 400,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 3:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 0,
        low: 20
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    status: "Running",
    label: "task-label",
    age: 10,
    name: "task-4",
    clusterIP: "10.148.0.3",
    cpuUsage: [
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 1:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 0.12,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 2:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 0.105,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 3:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 0.1,
        low: 20
      }
    ],
    memoryUsage: [
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 1:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 0,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 2:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 570,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 3:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 0,
        low: 20
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    status: "Not available",
    label: "task-label",
    age: 1440,
    name: "task-5",
    clusterIP: "10.148.0.3",
    cpuUsage: [
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 1:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 0.12,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 2:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 0.105,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 3:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 0.1,
        low: 20
      }
    ],
    memoryUsage: [
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 1:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 570,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 2:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 100,
        low: 20
      },
      {
        date: "2015-10-1 3:00 PM GMT+1:00",
        high: 400,
        low: 20
      }
    ]
  }
];

export default data;
```

One more note: if you don't want to use react-table because of its perceived complexity, i suggest you at least use Lodash for various sorting/grouping procedures. Doing vanilla JS is great if you want to learn, but if it's urgent and practical, Lodash can save you a lot of time and effort.

Comment: Thank you. I have already tried this approach, what happens is when sort by age button clicked it sorts data once and if I click again nothing happens. I have to click on cpu sort button, then it sorts again but not by cpu usage but by age again, and doesn't work if I click cpu again so have to click sort by age again...

Comment: I started playing with it, and i must say it's overly complicated...You need to simplify the logic...Also you have logical errors in the sorting function, like in the case of "age", you need to use > sign. Regarding cpu and memory, you need to first calculate the average, because u cant just compare objects...you have an array with "low" and "high" values there...If you're doing it for studying purposes, then keep going, but if u need it "to just work", i recommend using react-table

Comment: Would you please be able to have a look once again? I have updated the data and sorting different fields

Comment: Tommorow..now sleep time :D

Comment: Where is the updated code? the sandbox seems the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210721/discussion-between-edgar-kiljak-and-i-brod).

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need. Works like a charm! Great solution

Comment: Great :D Take a look at this, for the future: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15